# Hi all, I try to modify a static website hosted by github pages, but I have the following error:

Tags: git, github, ssh, passwords

`Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/omnislashh/anim_site.git/'` 
Any help, please? I have an SSH key for my computer already, so I don't understand why I can't push the modifications for this project.

I trying to folow the documentation, push and enter passwords asked, and even SSH just in case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh+remote%3A+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed

Comment: To use SSH keypair you should switch remote URL to `ssh://` protocol.